# How to show validation error as the django admin default errors

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is there any way to show validation error in a standard way as the other errors ?

```
class Student(models.Model):
...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        except ValidationError:
            raise forms.ValidationError("There aren't places anymore")
```

Comment: where you want to show it? in the modelform?

Comment: Yes, but in the form in the admin page, not in a view.

Comment: if you register a model in the admin it will generate error accordingly, you dont need to do anything

Comment: But the validationerror doesn't show the error as the others, It shows a page with ValidationError at ...

Comment: ok check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyModel(models.Model):

    def is_available(self):
        #do check here
        return result

    def clean(self):
        if not self.is_available():
            raise ValidationError('Item already booked for those dates')
```

Comment: I was making a mistake, forms.ValidationError was not for that purpose, ValidationError shows the error in the right way, thanks.

Comment: @Goun2 [forms.ValidationError *is* exceptions.ValidationError](https://github.com/django/django/blob/96a598356a9ea8c2c05b22cadc12e256a3b295fd/django/forms/__init__.py#L5)